# why when i enter less than 201 its also run the last if statement i don't enter understand

Tags: java

I do not understand the reason why this code is not working proper when I enter less than 200 then last if statement also executed can anyone tell the problem.

This the main problem of this code is not working properly

```
    public class main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    double unit   ;
    double extra;
    double total_unit;

    System.out.println("enter total unit");

    unit=input.nextInt();

    if(unit >=1 && unit <=200){

    unit=unit *8;

    System.out.println(" bill of 200 units is "+ unit);

    }

    if(unit  >=201 && unit <=300){

     extra = unit - 200;

     extra= extra * 10;

     total_unit = 200 * 8 + extra;

     System.out.println("Total bill is: " + total_unit); 

    }

    if(unit >=301 && unit<=400){

     extra=unit-300;

    extra=extra *15;

    total_unit=200*8 +100*10+ extra;

    System.out.println("total bill of more than 300 units is "+total_unit);

    }  

    if(unit >=401 && unit<=500){

     extra=unit-400;

    extra=extra*20;

     total_unit=200*8+ 100*10 + 100*15 + extra ;

    System.out.println("total bill between 401 to 500 units" + total_unit);

        }

     if(unit>501){  

     extra=unit-500;

    System.out.println("unit consumed  " + extra + "  that above");

    extra=extra *25;

    System.out.println("------------unit above 500 bill-------- \n"   +extra);
     total_unit=200*8 + 100*10 +100*15 +100*20 + extra;

    System.out.println("---------total bill----------\n  " +     total_unit);

    }

    }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: What else statement are you talking about? There is no else statement in the code you provided.

Comment: Please post expected output and actual output

Comment: Please give properly-indented code.

Comment: There is no else statement, maybe that is your problem.

Comment: You are multiplying unit by 8; further if statements are testing the higher value.  Use a different variable for the multipled value.

Comment: Ugly, awful, badly formatted code with names that fail to follow Java coding standards.  Read up on the DRY principle.

Comment: @antlersoft is right, and another way to handle it is to use `else if` (instead of just sequential `if`s) to ensure that only one block is run.

Comment: anlersoft yeah now its running good but tell  the reason why it didnot work with same variable i have the check of if statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have writen the answer in code why it is executing second condition read the comments in code. if you have any ?s post a comment

```
 //here your reading the unit value as ex: 190
 unit=input.nextInt(); 

 if (unit >= 1 && unit <= 200) {
        //here your changin the  unit value to 190 * 8 so now unit value is 1520
        unit = unit * 8;
        System.out.println(" bill of 200 units is " + unit);
  }
 //now here your given value is 190 but unit value is changed to 1520    here condition true, that is the reason second condition also excecuting.
 if (unit > 501) {
        extra = unit - 500;
        System.out.println("unit consumed  " + extra + "  that above");
        extra = extra * 25;
        System.out.println("------------unit above 500 bill-------- \n"
                + extra);
        total_unit = 200 * 8 + 100 * 10 + 100 * 15 + 100 * 20 + extra;
        System.out
                .println("---------total bill----------\n  " + total_unit);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is created because when you enter a number **less than 201**, your first `if` statement gets executed as follows:

```
if(unit >=1 && unit <=200){
    unit=unit*8; //Problem is here. Use another variable such as unitTemp = unit*8
    System.out.println(" bill of 200 units is " + unit); //Use unitTemp here too
}
```

Here, any number **less than 200** will be multiplied by 8 and assigned to the same `unit` variable and please note that the updated `unit` variable is further checked in the following `if` conditions and not it's previous value from the user input.

UPDATE: I also suggest using `else if` at every statement after your first `if` statement so it would only be executed once and thus your problem would vanish, but it's just a trick for your particular problem(if you only use this `else if` solution) so to better have a meaningful code, I suggest using both the tactics. It is not needed here as my above solution would work efficiently, but in the near future, eventually you will.